# Selecting more than one variable for analysis and visualization

Tags: visualization, numeric, analysis, categorical

[image: data image]

I know that i can use this function to select a numeric output of 1 specific categoric variable: hist(data$yield[yield$year=="2019, but is it also possible to also specify for crop type and year and maybe even three categorical variables? I don't find how i can arrange this.

I already tried to put some categorical variables behind it but it won't work